# Calling console app from IIS web service, not loading DLL's

Tags: web-services, iis, shellexecute

My iis service is calling a console app. This console app references a DLL.

When I check the error output I get this :

Could not load file or assembly 'file:///c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\MyDll.dll'

What is the correct way to call the executable:

So far I've tried this:

```
 using (var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
            {
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true; 
                p.StartInfo.FileName = downloaderPath;
                p.Start();
                string o = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                string i = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); 
                p.WaitForExit();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line:

```
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(downloaderPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "c:\mydir\";
```

If you don't, the executable will be started from the directory where IIS is running (c:\windows\system32\inetsrv).